# Cursor with where condition

Tags: database, oracle, loops, cursor

I have a cursor which contains bills of all the persons grouped by their family name. Now, I want to check dynamically that which family name has outstanding bill against it. For eg. there is adams and perry family and many more. The cursor has values for all the members of the families with one column being the family name. Now I check for the outstanding amount, I find their is one in adams family. Now, I want my cursor to display all the members of adams family so I can distribute the bill to the family's other members.

```
CURSOR individual_cur is
select name,family_name, bill from table1;

CURSOR family_cur is
    select family_name from table1;

    for temp in family_cur loop
    select sum(bill) into extra_bill where family_name is temp.family_name;

    if extra_bill <>0 then

    -- Now here I want 
    for temp1 in individual_cur loop *where family_name is temp.family_name*

    -- How to do this.
    end loop;
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use a slow cursor for this. This can be done with a single SQL query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you help me in this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541100/fetch-table-name-from-a-column-for-from-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example

```
declare
   -- add family name as parameter
   -- and use in where clause
   cursor individual_cur(p_family_name table1.family_name%type) is
      select name
            ,family_name
            ,bill
        from table1
       where family_name = p_family_name;

   --group by family 
   -- and filter on sum(bill)<>0
   cursor family_cur is
      select family_name
        from table1
       group by family_name
       having sum(bill)<>0;
begin

   for temp in family_cur
   loop
        -- select individuals from this family
         for temp1 in individual_cur(temp.family_name)
         loop

           -- do something
        end loop;
   end loop;
end;
```

Or in just one query

```
 select name
       ,family_name
       ,bill
   from table1
  where family_name in (select family_name
                        from table1
                        group by family_name
                        having sum(bill)<>0)
```

Comment: hey can you help me in this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541100/fetch-table-name-from-a-column-for-from-clause

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you're trying to do is average out the bill across all the family members? If so, then this can be done in a single query:

```
WITH table1 AS (SELECT 'bob' NAME, 'jones' family_name, 0 bill FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'jane', 'jones', 100 bill FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'fred', 'jones', 50 bill FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'bill', 'smith', 0 bill FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'brenda', 'smith', 60 bill FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'jill', 'smith', 0 bill FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'bob', 'ingles', 0 bill FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'carol', 'ingles', 0 bill FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'rob', 'carolgees', 200 bill FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your table1 with sample data in it - you wouldn't need this
-- see the SQL below
SELECT NAME,
       family_name,
       bill,
       AVG(bill) OVER (PARTITION BY family_name) split_bill
FROM   table1;

NAME   FAMILY_NAME       BILL SPLIT_BILL
------ ----------- ---------- ----------
rob    carolgees          200        200
carol  ingles               0          0
bob    ingles               0          0
fred   jones               50         50
bob    jones                0         50
jane   jones              100         50
jill   smith                0         20
bill   smith                0         20
brenda smith               60         20
```

This uses the `AVG()` analytic function to split the bill across all the members in the family, without compressing the rows like the `AVG()` aggregate function would do.

If you then needed to update table1 to reflect the shared bills, you could then plug the above query into a `MERGE` statement, something like:

```
merge into table1 tgt
  using (select name,
                family_name,
                bill,
                avg(bill) over (partition by family_name) split_bill
         from   table1) src
    on (tgt.name = src.name and tgt.family_name = src.family_name)
when matched then
update set tgt.bill = src.split_bill
where  tgt.bill != src.split_bill;
```

Comment: hey can you help me in this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541100/fetch-table-name-from-a-column-for-from-clause